# Highcharts using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: example]

Here i added image, I need help from your side, I marked in red color those annotations move when high-chart is zoom-out and zoom-in default set corners of charts.Here loading .csv file plotting graph using high-charts.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Please take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have problems because your are opening your webpage as a file, and not from a local webserver.

in the url field the is `file://`, is should be something like `localhost/`